# wpf datagrid selection changed

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid

I used to have the following code using a listview:

```
private void ListViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Exam exam in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                ViewModel.SelectedExams.Remove(exam);
            }
            foreach (Exam exam in e.AddedItems)
            {
                ViewModel.SelectedExams.Add(exam);
            }
        }
```

Now I changed to a datagrid but I'm getting an error message that says: Error   1   'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'RemovedItems' and no extension method 'RemovedItems' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private void DataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Exam exam in  e.RemovedItems)
        {
            ViewModel.SelectedExams.Remove(exam);
        }
        foreach (Exam exam in e.AddedItems)
        {
            ViewModel.SelectedExams.Add(exam);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone out there help me by telling me how I can capture the selected rows in a datagrid in the same way as I used to capture them in a listview.

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectionChanged` event of the DataGrid accepts `SelectionChangedEventArgs` as argument (the same as for the SelectionChanged event of the ListView), not the base `EventArgs`:

```
private void DataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

Here `e.RemovedItems` and `e.AddedItems` are available.

Answer (score 0):

SelectionChanged isn't even firing for me,

perhaps try `SelectedCellsChanged`? - More info at [WPF Datagrid: SelectionChanged event isn't raised when SelectionUnit="Cell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714325/wpf-datagrid-selectionchanged-event-isnt-raised-when-selectionunit-cell)

More about SelectionChanged on MSDN forums - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e1dc5abc-2f94-4653-a0a8-ee9b6adcb165

Also getting the selected cell's value at [WPF Toolkit DataGrid SelectionChanged Getting Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148978/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-selectionchanged-getting-cell-value)