# WPF Datagrid: SelectionChanged event isn't raised when SelectionUnit="Cell"

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm using the WPF toolkit datagrid. I have it set to **SelectionUnit="Cell"** and **SelectionMode="Extended"**.

The SelectionChanged event is never raised!

It works fine when the SelectionUnit is set to FullRow.

Am I Missing something?

BTW, the reason I need it is since I'm trying to create an Attached Property to help me bind the SelectedCells to my ViewModel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make use of `DataGrid.SelectedCellsChanged` which should [provide you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcellschanged.aspx) with what you need.

```
private void DG1_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the newly selected cells
    IList<DataGridCellInfo> selectedcells = e.AddedCells;

    //Get the value of each newly selected cell
    foreach (DataGridCellInfo di in selectedcells)
    {
        //Cast the DataGridCellInfo.Item to the source object type
        //In this case the ItemsSource is a DataTable and individual items are DataRows
        DataRowView dvr = (DataRowView)di.Item;

        //Clear values for all newly selected cells
        AdventureWorksLT2008DataSet.CustomerRow cr = (AdventureWorksLT2008DataSet.CustomerRow)dvr.Row;
        cr.BeginEdit();
        cr.SetField(di.Column.DisplayIndex, "");
        cr.EndEdit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Aaron's right. SelectionChanged does indeed work and provides the needed info.