# Datagrid: background colour + disable of selection depending on the cell value - using trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background, triggers

There is a lot of questions about WPF datagrids on SO, but I still have to ask mine cause I just can't get what I want from those... so don't be mad with me and try to help me by answering pretty please :].

**hint:** the main question is: *Why my trigger won't work?* :|

1. **Is there a datagrid property which disables selecting cell without value?** I think I knew there was something like that, but I can't find it now. If there isn't such a thing how would u solve this thing? I was thinking about the event on selectedCellsChanged or something like that. But I'm not sure how to work it out.
2. **How can I set background property of cell depending on the value inside?** Was looking for some text/content/value property for DatagridCell(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.aspx) but nothing worked for me...
   I know there is some value convertor but I was thinking of solving this using triggers.

Some info: I have set `SelectionMode="Extended"` + `SelectionUnit="Cell"`.

I have tried setting the background using trigger, but it didnt work:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasContent"  Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

The property `IsSelected` works ok, but the thing with no content doesn't. Is it just me thinking (wrong) that "" or `null` is no content?
Also tried `<Trigger Property="Content"  Value="">` and `<Trigger Property="Content"  Value="null">`, but these things just don't want to work for me. What's wrong with me???

**Edit:** I found this Q/A - [How do I change the background color of a cell using WPF Toolkit Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745132/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-cell-using-wpf-toolkit-datagrid) so I guess I will work the second Q with that, but still I don't see what's wrong with my trigger...
Also if my trigger worked I could somehow set the cell with `HasContent="False"` as not selectable if there is something like that. But I just need to get my trigger work :D

**Edit2:** When I set the `<Trigger Property="HasContent"  Value="True">` it works for all of my cells.. So I guess it takes null/"" as a value. That leaves me to question:

**How should I solve this if I want special background for nulls and disable their selection?**

**Edit3:** Disabling the selection should work like this: `<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>` thanks to [WPF ListView turn off selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051215/wpf-listview-turn-off-selection#comment863179_1051324) .. which ain't working :D :'(

Now I just need to work out the trigger about `null` content of cell... any hints?

Comment: It's a pretty simple code. It should work. Try it in a simple project. I believe there is somthing wrong with your view or grid settings.

Comment: @OlegIgnatov I updated the Q.. It's kinda weird that null is actually some content.

Comment: I don't have a code example for you, but I think this has to be done at the DataGridColumn level, e.g. use a DataGridTemplateColumn and in the DataTemplate specify bindings to value, isenabled and a background which can be shown/hidden if value is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to finally solve my problem with selecting empty cells.
I know it ain't the best solution, but it works for me :D
Thanks to this Q/A: [How Can Determine Selected Cell's Value In DataGrid? (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837876/how-can-determine-selected-cells-value-in-datagrid-wpf) it helped :).

```
private void mydatagrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.AddedCells)
            {
                var col = item.Column as DataGridColumn;
                var fc = col.GetCellContent(item.Item);

                if (fc is TextBlock)
                {
                    if (((fc as TextBlock).Text == (""))||((fc as TextBlock).Text == null))
                    {
                        mydatagrid.SelectedCells.Remove(item);
                        fc.Focusable = false; // not sure if neccesarry/working after the previous line
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The part about background colour is solved here: [How to set background of a datagrid cell during AutoGeneratingColumn event depending on its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645688/how-to-set-background-of-a-datagrid-cell-during-autogeneratingcolumn-event-depen)

If u have any complaints/improvements to my solution just add comments :).

Comment: You can make you code more elegant if utilize "as" operator and string.IsNullOrEmpty function.

var fc = col.GetCellContent(item.Item) as TextBlock;
if (fc != null && string.IsNulOrEmpty(fc.Text)) ...

Answer (score 1):

I create a simple `DataGrid` and try to find out why `HasContent` return always `true`. I check `Content` property and it has `TextBlock` in it. So probably this is a reason why it's always true.

To handle this issue you can modify your `Trigger` to use converter:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource CellConverter}}"  Value="False" >
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

And in converter check appropriate property if is null. To know which property converter should check you can use `ConverterParameter`.

It isn't an elegant solution... but it works ;)

Comment: Well thx, I think I get why the HasContent ain't working for me, but still nto sure how to get the convertor to work and I would rather try it some easier way without convertor.

Comment: Yes same comment - CellConverter needs to check for property X on the DataContext, however if this style is applied to all cells in all columns, you can't know which property to check for null.