# How to get the column value upon double-click in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following `DataGrid` in a WPF `Window`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name ="ElementDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="160" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" SelectionChanged="ElementDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Id" Width="*" Binding="{Binding id}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Category" Width="*" Binding="{Binding categName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to set it in a way that if I double-click on a cell containing an `id`, it redirects me to a method where I could describe the functionality that needs to happen.

I tried using an `EventSetter`, but it does not work with `DataGridTextColumn`.

```
<EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

Any code/useful documentation is highly welcome.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: if `DataGridTextColumn` doesn't support the concept well, you should consider implementation and using `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the event setter to the cell style.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick"/>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

From there on, you could can use the `sender`, which is the `DataGridCell`
to get the value.

```
private void DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var cell = (DataGridCell) sender;
   var item = (YourDataItemType) cell.DataContext;

   // The cell content depends on the column used.
   var textBox = (TextBox) cell.Column.GetCellContent(item);
   var value = textBox.Text;

   // ...do something with the value
}
```

Note that this is only one approach that [depends on the column used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.getcellcontent?view=net-5.0), these are alternatives:

- [How to read value from a Cell from a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5549321/6181599)
- [WPF Datagrid Get Selected Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19225568/6181599)

A different way is to create your own data templates in a `DataTemplateColumn` and use input bindings.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourDataItemType}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}">
            <TextBlock.InputBindings>
               <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                             Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding id}"/>
            </TextBlock.InputBindings>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourDataItemType}">
         <TextBox Text="{Binding id}">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
               <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                             Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding categName}"/>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
         </TextBox>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

A benefit here is that you can use commands directly and pass the value as `CommandParameter`.