# Allow ONLY ONE entity in datagrid to be 'preferred'

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

In my WPF DataGrid there is short list of phone numbers for a contact.  I want to allow ONLY ONE of the numbers to be marked as preferred.

The view model has a property for the contact (an entity from the database) and an ObservableCollection of related PhoneNumbers, also from the database.  Simplified PhoneNumbers entity looks like this:

```
    class PhoneNumbers
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNbr { get; set; }
    public bool Preferred { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
}
```

The DataGrid displays the PhoneNbr property in a DataGridTextColumn and the Preferred property in a DataGridCheckBoxColumn; the other properties aren't displayed.

In an ideal world, when the user checks a phone number in the DataGrid, all the other numbers would automatically be UNCHECKED.  Right now I have no control over this - they're free to check any or all of them.

So...I'm looking for guidance in how to make this happen.  Thanks

Comment: You should have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409744/control-radiobutton-datagridtemplatecolumn-from-code)

Comment: Sorry if I'm dense, but I don't see the relevance.  Did I misread it?  That appears to refer to the enabling of controls in a column where I'm looking for a way to hook the changed value of an EF entity's property so I can change the OTHER entities in the grid.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the use of `RadioButton` `DataTemplate` instead of using a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` since the point of having a `CheckBox` is to allow multiple selections, whereas the `RadioButton` (assuming you set the `GroupName` property to be the same`) only allows selection of one.

Comment: Interesting and intriguing.  I'll have to look at that in a new light.  Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Bob - Try as I might, there's no progress on this using the radiobutton template.  I've got the visual portion working, but the property change isn't firing for any of the entities.  I mean that the display allows only one row to show as Preferred, but the Preferred property - to which IsChecked is bound - isn't updating for any of the rows.

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your `PhoneNumbers` object.

Comment: I'm using EF 5 and created the model from the database, so it does implement it, that's why I'm stumped